# Lumen queue suddenly interrupted

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I got several jobs, processing with lumen

```
C:\projects\myproject (feature-1234 -> origin)
$ php artisan queue:work --queue=rate-parse,fetch-tickers,check-markets,make-rates,switch-exchange
```

but sometimes, treatment suddenly interrupted without any errors or messages, and not all queues finished

```
[2020-12-16 10:01:21][22152] Processing: App\Jobs\SwitchExchange
[2020-12-16 10:01:34][22152] Processed:  App\Jobs\SwitchExchange

C:\projects\myproject (feature-1234 -> origin)
```